# Google App Script - Why is getTemporaryActiveUserKey() returning the same value for unique users

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have created a contact type form using Google App script and published as a Web App.

As I need to determine that the users filling in the form are unique I have used the [getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTemporaryActiveUserKey()) function to get the users  unique key and save it to a spreadsheet alongside the rest of the form data.

However there has now been a number of instances where the script has returned the identical key for multiple different users. I know for a fact these users are using different browsers and are in completely different locations.

My question is, how is this possible?

Below is the function in code.gs which runs when the form is submitted which retrieves this value

```
function postFormDataToSheet(form){
  var responseSheet = SSDoc.getSheetByName("Results");

  var time = new Date()

  var userKey = Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey();
  var resultRow = [time,form.user_name, form.user_email, form.sheet,userKey]
  responseSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
}
```

And the JavaScript Function in the Form HTML which calls the above Function when the submit button is pressed

```
$(function(){
  $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(SuccessPage).postFormDataToSheet(this.form);    
  })
})
```

Webapp is published with the following settings

```
Execute the app as: Me (myemailaddress)

Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous
```

Comment: What is publish settings for your Web App, specifically what option set for "execute as.."?

Comment: @Kos Good question I did wonder if it could be related to that but decided it was unlikely as I have had 69 form submissions with 63 unqiue UserKeys.  

The Web App is published with the following settings:
Execute the app as: Me (myemailaddress)
Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous

Comment: The documentation does not state that the user must be signed in with a Google Account, but I don't see how the `getTemporaryActiveUserKey()` method could get a key that is unique to the active user, for an anonymous user.

Comment: I have discovered all incognito sessions have the same userkey regardless of the user/location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research and trialling various scenarios I have determined the following:

- The [getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#gettemporaryactiveuserkey) function will return a unique
  key for any user logged in with a google account ( Known as an
  [ActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) )
- If the user is not logged into a google account (or is using an incognito session) then [getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#gettemporaryactiveuserkey) still returns a key value BUT this is not unique to that user. This was the cause of the duplicate key I was receiving.
- To ensure ONLY unique keys are returned when publishing the web app it should be publish with the requirement that a user is logged in to access it.

*Based on the above my opinion is that the [getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#gettemporaryactiveuserkey) function should not return a value at all for users that are not logged in as I cannot see any use for such a key when is not unique to the user.*

Comment: How do you "require that a user is logged in to access it." when "Execute the app as me"

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out a way to get a unique key for anonymous users?

Comment: Its been a while and i'm no longer using the script that needed this. But from memory I just required all users to be logged into a Google account so anonymous access was no longer possible. This was fine for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

Your web app deployed with permission ["Execute 
the app as me"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions), it means the script *always executes as you*.

From documentation of [`Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#gettemporaryactiveuserkey):

> Gets a temporary key that is unique to the active user but does not reveal the user identity. The temporary key rotates every 30 days and is unique to the script.

As it based on **active user**, you will get the same result every time because for Google Apps Script you are the only *active user* for web app script, despite of who *do request* to the script.

If you want to be able to get different values for different users, you will need to ensure users are authorized, by using web app permission setting *"Execute the app as user accessing the web app"*.

Comment: I don't think this is true. ActiveUser(user at the keyboard) is not equal to EffectiveUser(the user under whose authority a script is executed). Furthermore, Your answer contradicts  OP's comment: `was unlikely as I have had 69 form submissions with 63 unqiue UserKeys.`

Comment: @I'-'I see [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) documentation: `the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization .. or a web app deployed to "execute as me"`

Comment: It proves the point. `or a web app deployed to "execute as me"` > Active user is someone who accesses a webApp deployed to "execute as me". `me` always has access to my identity/email. Temporary key is for Active user and does NOT reveal user's identity. `Gets a temporary key that is unique to the active user but does not reveal the user identity`

Comment: I see your point, but I still think active user exists only after authorization, in other case web app opened in 5 tabs will give you 5 different "active" users.

Comment: Agree...  You'll probably get 5 different unique keys. But that still doesn't answer OP's question as to why two of those 5 have the same userkeys. `I know for a fact these users are using different browsers and are in completely different locations`

Comment: I do not believe this is the cause of my issues. Opening the webapp in 5 different tabs gives the same userkey.